# Using get_feature() function on layer while editing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, features, vector-layer, relation

In QGIS, I am trying to update a feature based on entries made on a nested form (relation).

Considering:

- Layer1 has Field1 that should capture the value of Field 2, and field in Layer2
- Layer2 is nested in the form of Layer1 via a Relation.

The problem I have is that when I'm creating a feature this way, the `get_feature()` function won't get the value because it is not actually written in Layer2 until the editing is done, so the feature remains empty. If I then go back to the attribute table and update anything, the `get_feature()` will work, but I want this to happen without having to manually update every entry I do.

I tried several ways to use `current_value()` to get the value being edited in Layer2 but didn't find a way to make it work...

To test this, I'm using something as simple as this:

```
if(get_feature('Layer2', 'ID_OBS_Layer1', "ID_OBS_Layer2") is not NULL, 1, 2)
```

as a default value (with an update) for my field entry. This work for a feature where the editing is closed, but not while it is being edited.